# Error : major format is 0 (libsndfile, Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, audio, filter, libsndfile

I keep getting error mentioned in topic (no additional messages) when I'm trying to open the file in Qt using libsndfile library in following code:

```
    SNDFILE * outfile;
    SF_INFO sfinfo;

    //preparing output file
    sfinfo.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16;
    sfinfo.channels = 1;
    sfinfo.samplerate = 44100;

    memset( &sfinfo, 0, sizeof(SF_INFO));
    const char* path = "RainFilter.wav";

    outfile = sf_open(path, SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo);

    if(!(outfile))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create output file" << std::endl;
        sf_perror(outfile);
        return;
    }
```

This seems to be a problem with major part of the format property of sfinfo. I've tried most of the other formats, including numerical values such as:

```
sfinfo.format = 0x0B0000 | 0x0006;
```

What should I do? Is it the library-linking problem, environment problem or is the code incorrect? The path is irrelevant in this case, I've tried pointing to a different directory and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to

```
    memset(&sfinfo, 0, sizeof(sfinfo));

    //preparing output file
    sfinfo.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16;
    sfinfo.channels = 1;
    sfinfo.samplerate = 44100;
```

to *before* the assignment to the elements of sfinfo.  Even better, remove the call to memset, and zero-initialize the structure properly with:

```
    SFINFO sfinfo = {0};
    sfinfo.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16;
    sfinfo.channels = 1;
    sfinfo.samplerate = 44100;
```